# Nativescript 6 upgrade - Android build fails now

Tags: nativescript

I just upgraded to Nativescript 6 and when I try and run `tns android build --bundle` I get

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.
Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' fini
shed with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output. Run with --scan to get full insights.` (edited)
```

I updated all my plugins I saw that needed  it. Any ideas? Worked fine iOS

Comment: From which version you upgrade? Did you update your CLI too?

Comment: From `5.0.2` and yes, upgraded the CLI

Comment: Did you try a clean build by deleting platforms folder?

Answer (score 0):

So some plugins, even though updated, are not the correct ones anymore. The Nativescript plugins moved to private repos. Below are the listed ones I updated to:

```
"@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^1.0.0",
"@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.0.1",
"@proplugins/nativescript-localstorage": "^2.2.1",
"@proplugins/nativescript-zxing": "^1.6.0",
```